# How do I force jQuery to not automatically close a tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link and I want to create a `nav` tag before the link tag, then close it after the `a` tag.

code:

```
<a href="" id="test">link test</a>
```

I want the code will be like this:

```
<nav class="link-effect">
<a href="" id="test">link test</a>
</nav>
```

I tried the following `.before()`, `.after()`, `.append()`, `.prepend()` but the closing tag is created automatically.

Comment: Try [jQuery.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

Comment: Tags are HTML. When you're using JavaScript, you're using DOM nodes. If you create an element with a "tag", it's first being parsed into nodes. As such, `<nav>` is going to be invalid HTML, and be corrected as `<nav></nav>`. jQuery doesn't do this... the browser's built-in parser does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.wrap` function of jquery.

```
$( "#test" ).wrap( '<nav class="link-effect"></nav>' );
```

Please check below snippet.

```js
$( "#test" ).wrap( '<nav class="link-effect"></nav>' );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" id="test">link test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [jQuery.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#test').wrap('<nav class="link-effect"></nav>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="" id="test">link test</a>
```